# Unable to lazy load videos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, lazy-loading

so I found a piece of code for *lazy loading images*. And it works perfectly.

**This is the code:**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var lazyloadImages = document.querySelectorAll("img.lazy");    
  var lazyloadThrottleTimeout;

  function lazyload () {
     if(lazyloadThrottleTimeout) {
        clearTimeout(lazyloadThrottleTimeout);
     }    

  lazyloadThrottleTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
    lazyloadImages.forEach(function(img) {
        if(img.offsetTop < (window.innerHeight + scrollTop)) {
          img.src = img.dataset.src;
          img.classList.remove('lazy');
        }
    });
    if(lazyloadImages.length == 0) { 
      document.removeEventListener("scroll", lazyload);
      window.removeEventListener("resize", lazyload);
      window.removeEventListener("orientationChange", lazyload);
     }
    }, 20);
   }

  document.addEventListener("scroll", lazyload);
  window.addEventListener("resize", lazyload);
  window.addEventListener("orientationChange", lazyload);
  });
```

The problem is I need to *lazy load videos* as well, so I changed the **img** to **source**,

```
 var lazyloadImages = document.querySelectorAll("img.lazy");
```

to

```
var lazyloadVideos = document.querySelectorAll("source.lazy");
```

I thought it will work, but it doesn't and I have no clue why, can someone help me or point me to the right direction.

**This is the full code which I changed:**

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
 var lazyloadVideos = document.querySelectorAll("source.lazy");    
 var lazyloadThrottleTimeout;

 function lazyload () {
  if(lazyloadThrottleTimeout) {
    clearTimeout(lazyloadThrottleTimeout);
 }    

 lazyloadThrottleTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
    lazyloadVideos.forEach(function(source) {
        if(source.offsetTop < (window.innerHeight + scrollTop)) {
          source.src = source.dataset.src;
          source.classList.remove('lazy');
        }
    });
    if(lazyloadVideos.length == 0) { 
      document.removeEventListener("scroll", lazyload);
      window.removeEventListener("resize", lazyload);
      window.removeEventListener("orientationChange", lazyload);
     }
   }, 20);
  }

document.addEventListener("scroll", lazyload);
window.addEventListener("resize", lazyload);
window.addEventListener("orientationChange", lazyload);
});
```

**These are the HTML lines:**

```
<video loop class="image" onmouseover="this.play()" onmouseout="this.pause()">
   <source data-src="allvideos/1.mp4" type="video/mp4" class="lazy">
</video>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `var lazyloadVideos = document.querySelectorAll("source.lazy");` to `var lazyloadVideos = document.querySelectorAll("video.lazy");` and adding an event listener for them all separately using `forEach` or any other loop. Because the event listener should be on `video` tags not `source` tags

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: Try https://www.sitelint.com/blog/improved-lazy-loading-for-image-video-and-audio/